# Android - Image with title?

Tags: android, image, title

How can i set a title to a imagebutton/image or something that shows an icon?
So when i push the image for few seconds pop up me a little window with the title, like an item in action bar?

Comment: DO you want to just show the description of the Image or some other options related to the Image Button ?

Comment: description, just a little tittle when i push few seconds the "image" or imagebutton

Comment: when you declare items and put it in an action bar, if u push few seconds one of them pop up the title, i want that!

Comment: Please share the Layout Code, where you want the `ImageButton` to show this behavior, thanks.

Comment: it's a ImageButton by default but i'm asking if someone know a kind of button with image or somthing than have the same pecularity as an item than when you push it few seconds show you the title of the "item"

Comment: ActionBarSherlock duplicates this feature from the ActionBar. You could browse its source code and see how they coded their buttons for the ActionBar.

Comment: yesss i will! just wait me until tomorrow i will try them before check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This post demonstrates what you are looking for:
Link : http://androidresearch.wordpress.com/2012/05/06/how-to-create-popups-in-android/ 
You can make those pop-ups fade in and fade out. I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You could create your own solution around `OnLongClickListener` and `Toast`:

```
public class TitleImageButton extends ImageButton{
    private String mTitle;

    public TitleImageButton(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.setLongClickable(true);
        this.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener(){

        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View arg0) {
            if (mTitle != null) Toast.makeText(TitleImageButton.this.getContext(), mTitle, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    public void setTitle(String title){
         mTitle = title;
    }

    public String getTitle(){
        return mTitle;
    }   
}
```

Comment: You can look at the `onLongClick` method of `ActionMenuItemView` in ActionBarSherlock for how to adapt the toast's position to be near the button. See source here: https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/blob/master/actionbarsherlock/src/com/actionbarsherlock/internal/view/menu/ActionMenuItemView.java